# How to find data associated with windows defender processStart reference in windows10

Tags: windows-10, virus

Recently my windows defender warned me about a possibly malicious program it found on my pc. I have trouble interpreting the data windows defender serves me and I haven't found any microsoft documentation with regard to processStart.

The reports of windows defender are as following (my output is in dutch so I translated it to english):

1. Solution insufficient:

Detected: HackTool:Win32/Wpakill.AR!MTB

Status: Failure

This threat or this application may not be fully restored.

Date: 9-2-2022 20:01

Details: This program may show unwanted behaviour

Items involved:

process: pid:7576,ProcessStart:132889069092372720

2. Threat removed or restored:

Detected: HackTool:Win32/Wpakill.AR!MTB

Status: Removed or returned

This threat or app has been deleted from quarantaine or restored to the computer

Date: 9-2-2022 20:01

Details: This program may show unwanted behaviour

Items involved:

process: pid:708,ProcessStart:132889068914364653

Now, putting "HackTool:Win32/Wpakill.AR!MTB" into google, the true severity of my problem remains a little vague. The actual payload may or may not have been ran. This may or may not have dangerous effects on your OS. However my computer does suffer from weird symptoms like slow startup time, random crashes, CPU spikes, slow application responses. This has been the case for several years now, despite my regular malwarebytes scans and CHKDSK operations, so it's a bit difficult to link this to any specific event.

I have traced the PIDS with tasklist.

```
tasklist /FI "PID eq 7576"
```

> > > no tasks are running with the specified criteria

```
tasklist /FI "PID eq 708"
```

> > > Imagename: SystemSettingsBroker.exe, PID: 708, Session: Console, Session#: 1, Mem usage: 29.324 K

Checking SystemSettingsBroker.exe file properties, it does indeed show to have the microsoft SHA-256 verified signature.

I have searched on google for: -Windows defender how to interprete startProcess -Windows defender startProcess -Windows defender item specification -Windows defender startProcess item specification

My interpretation of stuff I have found online leads me to believe that the processStart is an entry to an event. I opened my eventviewer and searched all the logs at the specified date from windows defender, but couldn't find any irregularities. Then I tried querying the logs for the entry id using:

```
wevtutil qe Application /q:132889069092372720
```

> > > None

```
wevtutil qe Security /q:132889069092372720
```

> > > None

```
wevtutil qe System /q:132889069092372720
```

> > > None

Highly probable that I am using these commands wrongly. However I fear I may be too unexperienced to trace this issue any further without help. Can anybody give me a hint about how to trace this magical value of processStart offered by windows defender?

Comment: PIDs vary and are reused. There is no reason that a PID at one time is related to the same PID at another time.

Comment: I suppose that means it's not even certain that the process responsible for launching the supposed malicious action is SystemSettingsBroker.exe. However I do strongly feel that the long string provided by startProcess should be able to provide more details. I am trying to find out more about it through sysInternalsSuite tool and will probably end up answering my own question after some recon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see this occasionally. I have apps and tools that Windows Defender does not like.

When Windows Defender traps the offending App, you need to review (right then) and decide:

(a) This is my app and I can allow it. Then do that in the Windows Defender screen - the option will present itself.

(b) I do not know what this is. Allow Windows Defender to Quarantine the App.

If the App has been quarantined, you can go there and release it if that is the appropriate action.

The work is all manual - there is no overall setting to stop trapping your stuff.

Here is a screen shot of my allowed apps.

[image: Windows Defender Allowed Apps]

Comment: Thanks John for sharing your insights. Do you know how I can trace the processStart id, so that I can see exactly which process was responsible for launching the 'violation' in the eyes of windows defender? Is it tied to an event entry as I suspect?

Comment: You can try using Process Explorer (SysInternals - Microsoft) to find processes.  They can vary by app so I whitelist the App and that normally suffices.

Comment: In the screen shot I posted, I know what Cain is (Cain and Abel), and Piriform Bundler. But the other ones are related to main Apps that I have that WD trapped and that I whitelisted.

Comment: Thanks for elaborating. I can see why windows defender would see Cain and Abel as a threat :p I've downloaded sysInternalSuite, will try to proceed from there. I'd hoped that tracing this magic number would be possible from within normal windows cmdprompt. Guess it's not that easy.